# Click linha de uma Datatable jQuery e carregar uma página com informações do id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Estou listando informações do meu banco de dados em uma Datatable com jQuery e até aí está tudo ok.

O que eu quero fazer é ao clicar na 'row' da `Datatable` carregar naquela div todas as informações daquele ID que foi apresentado na tabela. Um exemplo do que quero fazer é tipo o gmail que aparece os emails na forma de lista e quando a pessoa clica carrega ele.

Como consigo fazer isso com uma Datatable?

Estou exibindo 10 itens na primeira página da tabela e, quando clico na linha, exibe a linha que eu quero. O problema é quando eu vou para a segunda ou terceira página e clico na linha o alert do JavaScript não funciona.

```
$(function() {
     var oTable = $("#tabelaaberto").dataTable({

        "oLanguage": {

            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ até _END_ no total de _TOTAL_ registros.",
            "sInfoEmpty": "",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado.",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar: ",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }               
        }       
    });

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $("#tabelaaberto tbody td").on('click',function(){
            var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
            alert(aData[0]);

        });
    });                
});
```

Comment: Decerto você terá que escrever algum `JavaScript` para detectar o clique e usar `Ajax` para carregar novos dados sob demanda. Você está familiarizado com isso? Na sua pergunta, faltou colar o link de exemplo.

Comment: @brasofilo Não é duplicata, pois esta pergunta é especificamente sobre o plugin DataTables

Comment: Por favor, inclua o código do que você conseguiu fazer até aqui. Você está montando toda a `<table>` e depois inicializando o plugin? Ou está usando a opção de puxar os dados por AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você está utilizando o JQuery DataTables OK?? [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Como não tem muitos detalhes na sua pergunta, presumo que seja apenas para exibir as informações, mas caso não seja é fácil de alterar. Já terá o caminho das pedras.
Irei exibir as informações em uma Dialog sobre o DataTable.

Você terá que fazer o seguinte, no DataTables existe a função de `fnDrawCallback`. Dentro dele teremos o código que você quer executar.
Que será algo semelhante a isto:

`oTable` é como declarei minha dataTable, basta alterar para a sua.

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function() {
    $('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {

        var INFO_01 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[0];
        var INFO_02 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[1];
        var INFO_03 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[2];
        var INFO_04 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[3];


          dialog = $( "#users-contain" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 500,
          width: 'auto',
          title: "Infos",
          modal: true,
          open: function( event, ui ) {

              $("#users tbody").empty();

             $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + INFO_01 + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + INFO_02 + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + INFO_03 + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + INFO_04 + "</td>" +
                  "</tr>" );

          },
          close: function( event, ui ) {
              $("#users tbody").empty();
           },
          buttons: {
            "OK": function(){
                dialog.dialog( "close" );           
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });

          dialog.dialog("open");
  } );
}
```

Além de que precisamos de um HTML para criar a DIV a ser exibida.

```
<div id="users-contain">
    <h1>Dados:</h1>
    <table id="users">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>INFO_01</th>
                <th>INFO_02</th>
                <th>INFO_03</th>
                <th>INFO_04</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa posta aí.

**--------------- Novo fonte -----------------**

```
$(function() {
     var oTable = $("#tabelaaberto").dataTable({

        "oLanguage": {

            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ até _END_ no total de _TOTAL_ registros.",
            "sInfoEmpty": "",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado.",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar: ",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }   
        },
        "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
            $('#tabelaaberto tbody td').on('click', function (e) {

                var INFO_01 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[0];
                var INFO_02 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[1];
                var INFO_03 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[2];
                var INFO_04 = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[3];

                alert("INFO 1: " + INFO_01 + "INFO 2: " + INFO_02 + "INFO 3: " + INFO_03 + "INFO 4: " + INFO_04);               

          } );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Poderia me ajudar com a pergunta que fiz abaixo ?

Comment: @PedroA. Adiciona o `"fnDrawCallback"` a seu exemplo... Logo abaixo do `"oAria"`, que ira funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: @PedroA. Adicionei o novo fonte a resposta... direto ao seu método. De uma olhada. Qualquer coisa grita aí.

Comment: Fernando, não da certo da sua forma. Estou usando essa template aqui http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/ e para comunicar com o banco JSP.

Comment: @PedroA. Aqui funciona, mas no CLICK utilizo `$('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {` Adiciono Classes as colunas usando o `"aoColumns" : [            {              "sClass" : "readonly",              "sTitle": "ID",              "aTargets": [0]             } ]`. Tentou debugar? Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Entao eu tenho uma página home.jsp que contém todo o menu do sistema (link que te passei acima). Ai quando mando carregar com ajax na div do centro ocorre perfeitamente, ou seja, busca na tabela, paginação tudo funcionando.
Quando tendo seleciona uma linha na primeira pagina funciona tudo certo, o problema acontece quando cliclo em uma linha da segunda ou superior página da tabela não exibindo o alert. Não sei se entendeu o meu problema ?

Comment: Sim sim. Entendi. Estranho, se dispara na primeira deveria funcionar nas demais... Pois é só uma referencia. No exemplo que montei aqui para teste funciona perfeitamente. Nas minhas DataTables só faço assim, abrindo as infos em uma Dialog.

Comment: Fernando, se você puder me dar uma força hora que tiver com tempo nesse link aqui tem o exemplo que estou utilizando a tabela. http://www.almsaeedstudio.com/. Tente colocar o modo que você faz e ve se funcionar e rapidinho. No menu do exemplo e a "Data tables". Valeu desde já pela força.

Comment: @PedroA. Está funcionando da maneira que te mostrei. Baixei aqui o exemplo do site que você passou, e implementei rapidamente. Segue o link: http://jsfiddle.net/xsy2vh9t/

Comment: A.W, consegui vou resolver eu estava esquecendo de passar o nome da tabela correto. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por nada. Qualquer coisa posta aí.